# 2FA of the Google Authenticator App with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, vba6

First of all I am not a native English speaker and new here. It is also not a question, but a possible solution.

I've been looking for a complete solution on how to implement the Google Authenticator App function in VBA. But all hmac and sha1 examples I found give wrong results.

Therefore, using other programming languages, I reproduced the logic. Sources that helped me from the community are given in the source code.

The code works for me, but I am an amateur in VBA. Maybe it is helpful and any optimization is welcome to me.

```
Private Type SYSTEMTIME
    wYear As Integer
    wMonth As Integer
    wDayOfWeek As Integer
    wDay As Integer
    wHour As Integer
    wMinute As Integer
    wSecond As Integer
    wMilliseconds As Integer
End Type
Private Declare Sub GetSystemTime Lib "Kernel32" (ByRef lpSystemTime As SYSTEMTIME)

Sub otp()
    Dim Key As String, Secret As String, Time As String, hmac As String, ch As String, p1 As String, p2 As String, otp As String
    Dim offset As Long, d As Long, i As Long, n As Long, j As Long, a As Long
    Secret = UCase("<replace with secret from QR>")
    If Len(Secret) >= 20 Then
        n = 0
        j = 0
    
        ' stackoverflow.com/questions/60327784/converting-from-base-32-to-decimal-without-vba
        ' Change: use base32 variant
        For i = 1 To Len(Secret)
            ch = Mid$(Secret, i, 1)
            If ch >= "A" And ch <= "Z" Then
                d = asc(ch) - asc("A")
            ElseIf ch >= "2" And ch <= "7" Then
                d = asc(ch) - asc("0") + 24
            End If
            ' www.idontplaydarts.com/2011/07/google-totp-two-factor-authentication-for-php/
            ' reproduced
            n = (ShiftLeft(n, 5)) + d
            j = j + 5
            If j >= 8 Then
                j = j - 8
                Key = Key & WorksheetFunction.Dec2Hex(ShiftRight((n And ShiftLeft(255, j)), j), 2)
            End If
        Next i
        Time = Right("0000000000000000" & Hex(WorksheetFunction.Floor(CurrentTimeMillis() / 1000 / 30, 1)), 16)
        hmac = HEX_HMACSHA1(Time, Key)
        offset = Hex2UInt(Right(hmac, 1))
        p2 = Hex2UInt("7fffffff")
        If offset = 0 Then
            p1 = Hex2UInt(Left(hmac, 8))
        Else
            p1 = Hex2UInt(Mid(hmac, offset * 2 + 1, 8))
        End If
        otp = Right(WorksheetFunction.Bitand(p1, p2), 6)
        Debug.Print otp
    End If
    
End Sub


' stackoverflow.com/questions/29772224/get-unix-time-milliseconds
Function CurrentTimeMillis() As Double
    ' Returns the milliseconds from 1970/01/01 00:00:00.0 to system UTC
    Dim st As SYSTEMTIME
    GetSystemTime st
    Dim t_Start, t_Now
    t_Start = DateSerial(1970, 1, 1) ' Starting time for Linux
    t_Now = DateSerial(st.wYear, st.wMonth, st.wDay) + _
        TimeSerial(st.wHour, st.wMinute, st.wSecond)
    CurrentTimeMillis = DateDiff("s", t_Start, t_Now) * 1000 + st.wMilliseconds
End Function

' stackoverflow.com/questions/40213758/convert-hex-string-to-unsigned-int-vba
Function Hex2UInt(h As String) As Double
    Dim dbl As Double: dbl = CDbl("&h" & h)

    If dbl < 0 Then
        dbl = CDbl("&h1" & h) - 4294967296#
    End If

    Hex2UInt = dbl
End Function

' mrexcel.com/board/threads/hmac-sha1-hash-hex-input-string.1137771/
' Change: use byte array with unsigned integer and return hex with leading zeros
Public Function HEX_HMACSHA1(ByVal sTextToHash As String, ByVal sSharedSecretKey As String) As String
    Dim asc                 As Object
    Dim enc                 As Object
    Dim TextToHash()        As Byte
    Dim SharedSecretKey()   As Byte
    Dim Bytes()             As Byte
    Dim sHexString          As String
    Dim i                   As Long
    
    Set asc = CreateObject("System.Text.UTF8Encoding")
    Set enc = CreateObject("System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA1")
    
    TextToHash = HexStringToByteArray(sTextToHash)
    SharedSecretKey = HexStringToByteArray(sSharedSecretKey)
    enc.Key = SharedSecretKey
    
    Bytes = enc.ComputeHash_2((TextToHash))
    HEX_HMACSHA1 = ByteArrayToHexStr(Bytes)
    Set asc = Nothing
    Set enc = Nothing
End Function

' stackoverflow.com/questions/44979363/excel-vba-regex-function-that-returns-multiple-matches-into-a-single-cell
' Change: create byte array with unsigned integer
Function HexStringToByteArray(strInput As String) As Byte()

Dim rMatch As Object
Dim s As String
Dim arrayMatches() As Byte
Dim i As Long


With New RegExp
    .Global = True
    .MultiLine = True
    .IgnoreCase = True
    .Pattern = "([A-F0-9]{2})"
    If .Test(strInput) Then
        For Each rMatch In .Execute(strInput)
            ReDim Preserve arrayMatches(i)
            arrayMatches(i) = Hex2UInt(rMatch.Value)
            i = i + 1
        Next
    End If
End With

    HexStringToByteArray = arrayMatches
End Function

' https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?559398-Byte-array-to-hex-string
' Change: removed Spaces between Hex
Function ByteArrayToHexStr(b() As Byte) As String
   Dim n As Long, i As Long
   
   ByteArrayToHexStr = Space$(2 * (UBound(b) - LBound(b)) + 2)
   n = 1
   For i = LBound(b) To UBound(b)
      Mid$(ByteArrayToHexStr, n, 2) = Right$("00" & Hex$(b(i)), 2)
      n = n + 2
   Next
End Function

' xbeat.net/vbspeed/c_ShiftLeft.htm
Public Static Function ShiftLeft(ByVal Value As Long, ByVal ShiftCount As Long) As Long
' by Jost Schwider, jost@schwider.de, 20010928
  Dim Pow2(0 To 31) As Long
  Dim i As Long
  Dim mask As Long
  
  Select Case ShiftCount
  Case 1 To 31
  
    'Ggf. Initialisieren:
    If i = 0 Then
      Pow2(0) = 1
      For i = 1 To 30
        Pow2(i) = 2 * Pow2(i - 1)
      Next i
    End If
    
    'Los gehts:
    mask = Pow2(31 - ShiftCount)
    If Value And mask Then
      ShiftLeft = (Value And (mask - 1)) * Pow2(ShiftCount) Or &H80000000
    Else
      ShiftLeft = (Value And (mask - 1)) * Pow2(ShiftCount)
    End If
  
  Case 0
  
    ShiftLeft = Value
  
  End Select
End Function

' xbeat.net/vbspeed/c_ShiftRight.htm
Public Static Function ShiftRight(ByVal Value As Long, ByVal ShiftCount As Long) As Long
' by Donald, donald@xbeat.net, 20011009
  Dim lPow2(0 To 30) As Long
  Dim i As Long
  
  Select Case ShiftCount
  Case 0 To 30
    If i = 0 Then
      lPow2(0) = 1
      For i = 1 To 30
        lPow2(i) = 2 * lPow2(i - 1)
      Next
    End If
    If Value And &H80000000 Then
      ShiftRight = Int(Value / lPow2(ShiftCount))
    Else
      ShiftRight = Value \ lPow2(ShiftCount)
    End If
  Case 31
    If Value And &H80000000 Then
      ShiftRight = -1
    Else
      ShiftRight = 0
    End If
  End Select
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

1. I would change `Sub otp()` to `Sub GetOneTimePassCode()` to prevent ambiguity between it and `otp as String`.
2. Also, in the function `Public Function HEX_HMACSHA1`, there is a variable `Dim asc as Object`.  `Asc()` is actually a built in function and naming variables the same thing could cause issues if you're debugging your code.  Generally a good practice to not do that in VBA.  Also, in this method, `asc` isn't actually used for anything.  You initialize it, but its never passed as an argument or invoked in any way.  This can be removed.  I've tested it the relevant lines commented out and it still works.
3. If I were to use this, I'd make `GetOneTimePassCode` a function that returns a `String` instead of just `Debug.Print`-ing it out.  Maybe it could even take `Secret` as an argument so it can work with any key rather than just the hardcoded one.
4. Alternatively, a function called `CheckOTP(codeToCheck as string) as boolean` that is exposed to the client and checks if the code was valid (returns `true` if valid) would probably be the best way to go.

```
#If VBA7 Then
   Private Declare PtrSafe Sub GetSystemTime Lib "Kernel32" (ByRef lpSystemTime As SYSTEMTIME)
#Else
   Private Declare Sub GetSystemTime Lib "Kernel32" (ByRef lpSystemTime As SYSTEMTIME)
#End If


Private Type SYSTEMTIME
   wYear As Integer
   wMonth As Integer
   wDayOfWeek As Integer
   wDay As Integer
   wHour As Integer
   wMinute As Integer
   wSecond As Integer
   wMilliseconds As Integer
End Type




Public Function CheckOTP(codeToCheck as String) as Boolean
   If Len(codeToCheck) < 6 Or Len(codeToCheck) > 7 Then Exit Function   'Not all, but most are 6 or 7 digits.
   If Not IsNumeric(codeToCheck) Then Exit Function                     'Code should always be numeric.
   If codeToCheck = GetOneTimePassCode(GetOTPSecret(UserID:=1)) Then CheckOTP = True
End Function


'Insert whatever code or logic you would use to get the Secret key.  Maybe the keys are in a Range and you need OTP's for all of them.
'Or maybe its USER based and depending on which user it is, you return a different key.  This is just a rudimentary example.
'How you implement this would be more determined by your needs than anything else.  So long as the output is the secret key needed to pass to GetOTP().
Private Function GetOTPSecret(UserID as Integer) as string
   Select Case UserID
      Case 1:        GetOTPSecret = UCase$("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEF")   'Bob's UserID
      Case Else:     GetOTPSecret = vbNullString
   End Select
End Function


Public Function GetOneTimePassCode(Secret As String) As String
   Dim Key As String, Time As String, hmac As String, ch As String, p1 As String, p2 As String
   Dim offset As Long, d As Long, i As Long, n As Long, j As Long, a As Long
   
   If Len(Secret) <= 20 Then Exit Function
   n = 0
   j = 0
   ' stackoverflow.com/questions/60327784/converting-from-base-32-to-decimal-without-vba
   ' Change: use base32 variant
   For i = 1 To Len(Secret)
      ch = Mid$(Secret, i, 1)
      If ch >= "A" And ch <= "Z" Then
         d = Asc(ch) - Asc("A")
      ElseIf ch >= "2" And ch <= "7" Then
         d = Asc(ch) - Asc("0") + 24
      End If
      ' www.idontplaydarts.com/2011/07/google-totp-two-factor-authentication-for-php/
      ' reproduced
      n = (ShiftLeft(n, 5)) + d
      j = j + 5
      If j >= 8 Then
         j = j - 8
         Key = Key & WorksheetFunction.Dec2Hex(ShiftRight((n And ShiftLeft(255, j)), j), 2)
      End If
   Next i
   Time = Right("0000000000000000" & Hex(WorksheetFunction.Floor(CurrentTimeMillis() / 1000 / 30, 1)), 16)
   hmac = HEX_HMACSHA1(Time, Key)
   offset = Hex2UInt(Right(hmac, 1))
   p2 = Hex2UInt("7fffffff")
   If offset = 0 Then
      p1 = Hex2UInt(Left(hmac, 8))
   Else
      p1 = Hex2UInt(Mid(hmac, offset * 2 + 1, 8))
   End If
   GetOneTimePassCode = Right(WorksheetFunction.Bitand(p1, p2), 6)
End Function



' stackoverflow.com/questions/29772224/get-unix-time-milliseconds
Private Function CurrentTimeMillis() As Double
' Returns the milliseconds from 1970/01/01 00:00:00.0 to system UTC
   Dim st As SYSTEMTIME
   GetSystemTime st  'API Call
   Dim t_Start, t_Now
   t_Start = DateSerial(1970, 1, 1) ' Starting time for Linux
   t_Now = DateSerial(st.wYear, st.wMonth, st.wDay) + TimeSerial(st.wHour, st.wMinute, st.wSecond)
   CurrentTimeMillis = DateDiff("s", t_Start, t_Now) * 1000 + st.wMilliseconds
End Function






' stackoverflow.com/questions/40213758/convert-hex-string-to-unsigned-int-vba
Private Function Hex2UInt(h As String) As Double
   Dim dbl As Double: dbl = CDbl("&h" & h)
   If dbl < 0 Then dbl = CDbl("&h1" & h) - 4294967296#
   Hex2UInt = dbl
End Function








' mrexcel.com/board/threads/hmac-sha1-hash-hex-input-string.1137771/
' Change: use byte array with unsigned integer and return hex with leading zeros
Private Function HEX_HMACSHA1(ByVal sTextToHash As String, ByVal sSharedSecretKey As String) As String
   'Dim Asc                 As Object
   Dim enc                 As Object
   Dim TextToHash()        As Byte
   Dim SharedSecretKey()   As Byte
   Dim Bytes()             As Byte
   Dim sHexString          As String
   Dim i                   As Long
   
   'Set Asc = CreateObject("System.Text.UTF8Encoding")
   Set enc = CreateObject("System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA1")
   
   TextToHash = HexStringToByteArray(sTextToHash)
   SharedSecretKey = HexStringToByteArray(sSharedSecretKey)
   enc.Key = SharedSecretKey
   
   Bytes = enc.ComputeHash_2((TextToHash))
   HEX_HMACSHA1 = ByteArrayToHexStr(Bytes)
   'Set Asc = Nothing
   Set enc = Nothing
End Function








' stackoverflow.com/questions/44979363/excel-vba-regex-function-that-returns-multiple-matches-into-a-single-cell
' Change: create byte array with unsigned integer
Private Function HexStringToByteArray(strInput As String) As Byte()
   Dim rMatch As Match
   Dim s As String
   Dim arrayMatches() As Byte
   Dim i As Long
   
   With New RegExp
      .Global = True
      .MultiLine = True
      .IgnoreCase = True
      .Pattern = "([A-F0-9]{2})"
      If .Test(strInput) Then
         For Each rMatch In .Execute(strInput)
            ReDim Preserve arrayMatches(i)
            arrayMatches(i) = Hex2UInt(rMatch.Value)
            i = i + 1
         Next
      End If
   End With
   HexStringToByteArray = arrayMatches
End Function








' https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?559398-Byte-array-to-hex-string
' Change: removed Spaces between Hex
Private Function ByteArrayToHexStr(b() As Byte) As String
   Dim n As Long, i As Long
   ByteArrayToHexStr = Space$(2 * (UBound(b) - LBound(b)) + 2)
   n = 1
   For i = LBound(b) To UBound(b)
      Mid$(ByteArrayToHexStr, n, 2) = Right$("00" & Hex$(b(i)), 2)
      n = n + 2
   Next
End Function





' xbeat.net/vbspeed/c_ShiftLeft.htm
Private Static Function ShiftLeft(ByVal Value As Long, ByVal ShiftCount As Long) As Long
' by Jost Schwider, jost@schwider.de, 20010928
   Dim Pow2(0 To 31) As Long
   Dim i As Long
   Dim mask As Long
   
   Select Case ShiftCount
      Case 1 To 31
         'If necessary, Initialize
         If i = 0 Then
            Pow2(0) = 1
            For i = 1 To 30
               Pow2(i) = 2 * Pow2(i - 1)
            Next i
         End If
         
         'Lets go
         mask = Pow2(31 - ShiftCount)
         If Value And mask Then
            ShiftLeft = (Value And (mask - 1)) * Pow2(ShiftCount) Or &H80000000
         Else
            ShiftLeft = (Value And (mask - 1)) * Pow2(ShiftCount)
         End If
      Case 0
         ShiftLeft = Value
   End Select
End Function







' xbeat.net/vbspeed/c_ShiftRight.htm
Private Static Function ShiftRight(ByVal Value As Long, ByVal ShiftCount As Long) As Long
' by Donald, donald@xbeat.net, 20011009
' Static function preserves ALL local variable values between function calls
   Dim lPow2(0 To 30) As Long
   Dim i As Long
   
   Select Case ShiftCount
      Case 0 To 30
         If i = 0 Then
            lPow2(0) = 1
            For i = 1 To 30
               lPow2(i) = 2 * lPow2(i - 1)
            Next
         End If
         If Value And &H80000000 Then
            ShiftRight = Int(Value / lPow2(ShiftCount))
         Else
            ShiftRight = Value \ lPow2(ShiftCount)
         End If
      Case 31
         If Value And &H80000000 Then
            ShiftRight = -1
         Else
            ShiftRight = 0
         End If
   End Select
End Function
```

You could wrap all of this up in a public static class and call it from whatever project you wanted to.  I'd still leave `GetOneTimePassCode` as public though so it can be implemented in everything that could need it and not dependent on your specific `GetOTPSecret` implementation for everything.

Only thing you would need is a reference to VBScript (Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5) for the RegExp.  Sorry, I hate late binding and refuse to use it unless I have to.

Comment: Great answer! However, I think there is a typo as the `CheckOTP` Function ends with `Exit Function` not `End Function`. Also just to clarify (to make it easier for future readers of your answer as the relevant libraries are not always that easy to find in the VBE's unhelpful 'References' dialog) that the full name of the required library is 'Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions' ... on my device I have two versions: your code works with version 5.5 but not with version 1.0 as 1.0 is missing the `Multiline` property of the `RegExp` object.

Comment: Good catch!  Thanks.

Comment: Interesting will need a closer look.  Appears  a few things I've  worked on with DateTime functions and Bit shifting for longs [Int32Bitwise](https://github.com/MarkJohnstoneGitHub/VBA-Library/blob/main/scr/Bitwise/Int32Bitwise.cls) Also Regex thou using  COM wrappers of .Net for that in another  project.